# how to make dynamic arrays of classes in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

i would like to make a dynamic array of classes in C++.

So if we have in a first attempt:

```
class A {

};
```

and then i want to have an array of pointers of class A:

```
class B {
    A * classes_a[16] = {nullptr};
    public:
    B()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
                classes_a[i] = new A();
    }
};
```

Well, this way is stright, i mean is an array of "A" pointer classes.

But, what i want to do, and i dont know how to do it isn't havinga fixed array of "A" pointers.
So the code would be the following:

```
class B {
    A ** classes_a = nullptr;
    public:
    B()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
                classes_a[i] = new A();     //this cannot be done
    }
};
```

What i want to do is, if i want 16 elements of class "A" pointers. There must be some way to not have a fixed "array" of pointers. I would like to have, for example: 8 class A pointers, ot 12 or whatever i like.

How to do it?

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" in C++, your next thought should always be `std::vector`.

Comment: And unless you need it for polymorphism (and if you don't know what that term means, then you don't need it) use a vector of *objects*, not pointers. As in `std::vector<A>`.

Comment: I know, but i wanted to do it by myself

Comment: Get yourself about another years experience in C++, until then use `std::vector`.  new/delete manual memory management are advanced topics since C++11.

Comment: What does your books or tutorials say about `new` and **`new[]`**?

Comment: The don't say to much. I know i have to use new. But i don't know the systax fox particullary case

Comment: No you don't need new (if you do then someone is not teaching you currenct C++) C++ says [don't use new/delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) unless you are writing datastructures from scratch. So as said use std::vector, and if you must allocate memory dynamically use std::make_unique.

Comment: @Lucas *"I know, but i wanted to do it by myself"*  Then maybe start by looking at your compiler's `<vector>` header, and consider why it is over 3000 lines long. Then be grateful that you don't *have to* write that yourself!  :-)

Comment: The use of `new` is an advanced C++ technique, and one that you shouldn't need to use in code except in very specific and specialized use cases.  I haven't needed to use `new` in over 10 years, in a very large C++ project.

Comment: @Lucas consider that most (online) C++ material is years and years old and still show `new`. Consider those materials outdated.  And like Eljay I hardly haven't used `new` since C++11 came out.  Only in datastructures I sometimes have to use std::make_unique, or std::make_shared but even there it is rare.

Comment: `std::vector<A*>` is the first approximation. But what you should do instead is a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`. And, most likely, what you _really want_ is just a `std::vector<A>`. Pointer jumping is inefficient; just don’t do it unless you have to.